# Core Data Structure for Survey App

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm having some trouble sketching out the model objects for a survey app. The app should enable the user to create a survey object with questions with suggested multi-choice answers, and then allow the user populate multiple copies of this survey with answers.

Creating a survey requires:

Entities:
Survey Template
// which has many
Questions
// which has either
TextField Question
// or
Multiple-Choice Question

Each of these can be populated with relevant information for the questions, suggested answers etc.

When I then want to create a survey answer object what do I do? A different table called Completed Surveys that somehow copies the questions across and provides space for answers?

I'm sure its straightforward, its just melting my head a bit, any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is by no means straight forward. Here is what I would do:

```
Template <----->> Question   
Template <----->> Survey   
Survey   <----->> Answer    
Question <----->> Answer
```

To distinguish the types you could have a `type` attribute (NSNumber, enum) that describes the type of the question. The answer entity would have both a numeric attribute (for the choice) and a string attribute (for the answer), which can stay unused according to which type question the answer refers to.